# Upgrading Unity to 5.11

Tags: unity-container

We have an old code which has

```
public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
{
  var type = context.OriginalBuildKey.Type;
```

Now it has to be

```
public override void PreBuildUp(ref BuilderContext context)
{
```

What's corresponding to `OriginalBuildKey` property in the `context` that is now of type `BuilderContext`? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had the same issue trying to update [AutoMoq-Unity5](https://github.com/MarkZither/AutoMoq-Unity5) to Unity 5.11.

[Comparing](https://github.com/unitycontainer/container/commit/cc51078486412d42e891df9dd5100d0b10985ebc#diff-8a12a86cd6e45ceeb3ecd62367b605d4) the current version of [BuilderContext.cs](https://github.com/unitycontainer/container/blob/b737bb32f17c39b174103aae86b63b95b302636a/src/Builder/Context/BuilderContext.cs) with the earlier 5.9 version I saw the change was

From

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Resolving: {OriginalBuildKey.Type},  Name: {OriginalBuildKey.Name}")]
    public class BuilderContext : IBuilderContext
```

To

```
    [DebuggerDisplay("Resolving: {Type},  Name: {Name}")]
    public struct BuilderContext : IResolveContext
```

So as you mentioned I changed my code from

```cs
        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
```

To use the BuilderContext by reference

```cs
        public override void PreBuildUp(ref BuilderContext context)
        {
```

And where I used `OriginalBuildKey.Type` I now have changed from

```cs
        private static Type GetTheTypeFromTheBuilderContext(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            return (context.OriginalBuildKey).Type;
        }
```

to

```cs
        private static Type GetTheTypeFromTheBuilderContext(IResolveContext context)
        {
            return context.Type;
        }
```

My unit tests are passing at that.